# NoSuchFieldError but the field is there

Tags: java, hibernate

I just upgraded a library, and another one started throwing `NoSuchFieldError`. It would be fine, if the field was removed. But it stays. It's just deprecated.

```
Hibernate.TIMESTAMP.nullSafeGet(null, null); // << works

new PersistentDateTime().nullSafeGet(null, null); // << throws NoSuchFieldError
```

where the the `nullSafeGet` method has:

```
Hibernate.TIMESTAMP.nullSafeGet(resultSet, string);
```

(of course, the field that is not found is `TIMESTAMP`)

the correct version of the library is on the classpath (otherewise my manual test would not have worked as well)

Why is that happening?

Update: I made a new class, overriding the old one, and defining the same method, with the exactly same code, and it works now. Any idea what's supposed to be happening in the bytecode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joshua Bloch explained this in his [short presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcY8cYfAEwU) - `static final` fields are copied into the client library, so it should be recompiled when a constant changes.

Comment: Apologies for re-opening this discussion, but I'm curious - how would this result in a NoSuchFieldError? I would expect a program that uses a static final variable defined in a library to just use the old value, not the new value if we access it.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that `PersistentDateTime()` returns an instance of some class that was compiled against a different version of `Hibernate`.

Comment: that's for sure. But since the field is there, it should be found, shouldn't it?

Comment: if every library had to be recompiled after non-structural changes are made in another library, they could never interoperate

Comment: Right Bozho, but TIMESTAMP is a constant, constants are inlined by the compiler and TIMESTAMP is org.hibernate.type.TimestampType.INSTANCE. If this type changed between versions, the constant may no longer be compatibel.

Comment: @Arne Burmeister I think that this particular constant can't be inlined, because it requires object instantiation.